# UIImageView won't load the image

Tags: ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to explore UIImageView so I added an image "Logo.jpg" to my projet (I'm new to iPad programming) which is LoadImageProject but iI can't get this image load to my view?

In my Interface builder (**LoadImageViweController.xib**) I drag a UIImageView and added it then connect it to the File's owner

My code :

> LoadImageViweController.h

```
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;

@end
```

and in the implementation file *LoadImageViweController.m* i added this to the **viewDidLoad** method :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //declare the Image
    UIImage *logo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo.jpg"];
    // init the UIImageView with the logo image
    [self.image initWithImage:logo];

}
```

When iI run it iI got always get blank screen? Why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the file correctly to your project?  Sometimes I find it tricky to add it properly.  You have to clean and run your project when adding new resources (such as images in your case) for the script to recognize your resources.

Comment: Thanks alexy13, i'm sure it's added on my project

Comment: You might want to post the xcode project to see if there is an issue with the nib connections or something similar.

Comment: Thanks problem solved. using : image.image = logo. Thanks for your reply and effort.

Answer (score 2):

Just use this in your viewDidLoad method..

```
 image.image = logo;
```

This will help you definitely....